# How to animate converging iterations

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, animation, python-3.6

I'm trying to animate the convergence over a number of iterations for the 1-D Gerchberg-Saxton algorithm but haven't managed to get it to work using matplotlib.animation or drawnow. I can plot them all on one graph simultaneously by using a for loop in the following code  but would like to see them sequentially. Can anyone help?

```
import numpy as np
import pyfftw.interfaces.numpy_fft as fft
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

aperture_width = 10
constraint_factor = 11
num_points = 2**16 
aperture_x = np.linspace(-20*aperture_width, 20*aperture_width, num_points)

# object to be recovered
g = np.array( abs(aperture_x) < (aperture_width/2), dtype=np.complex128)

# Field at Image plane
G = fft.fftshift(fft.fft(fft.fftshift(g)))

#Intensity at Image plane
G = abs(G)**2     # Only known value

constraint = np.array( abs(aperture_x) < (constraint_factor/2))  #object constraint - guess of object size

Gp = np.copy(G)  # make a copy of G

for i in range(10):

    gp = fft.fftshift(fft.ifft(fft.fftshift(np.sqrt(Gp))))     # first object "guess"
    gp = gp*constraint                                        # apply constraint to object

    Gp= fft.fftshift(fft.fft(fft.fftshift(gp)))              # calculate new image plane
    Gp = np.sqrt(G)*np.exp(1j*np.angle(Gp))                     # apply image domain constraint

    plt.plot(aperture_x,abs(G)**2/max(abs(G)**2),aperture_x,abs(Gp)**2/max(abs(Gp)**2))
    plt.xlim(-3,3)
    plt.pause(0.05)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

to plot the animation use
`plt.pause(0.05) #0.05 is time in secs`
between the plots.
Here is an example code

```
import matplotlib as plt

listValues = [i for i in range(0,10)] #random list just to show the basic concept

figure = plt.figure() #initialise figure object outside the loop
ax = figure.add_subplot(1,1,1) # get the subplot
for idx in listValues:
    ax.scatter(idx,idx) # here is your plotting
    plt.pause(0.05)

plt.show()
```

Comment: when I use plt.pause() I get the iterations appearing on different individual graphs appearing one after the other, is that using one of the aforementioned animation functions?

Comment: use `plt.show()` after the loop finishes not just after `plt.pause()`

Comment: thanks, just tried it but it's still giving me the same

Comment: can you pls update the code in the post so that i can have more clarity ?
and also pls make sure that when you initialise your figure / axis for the plot you do it outside the loop .
I have updated my answer to show the basic usage of how to animate things

Comment: just edited now, wasn't sure how to initialise before your edit. does the suggested for loop replace the one that I had?

Comment: yes. and also instead of plt .plot or plt.xlim use the ax object like how i created. i.e use ax.plot() and ax.xlim()

Comment: I tried to use ax.xlim(-3,3) but this doesn't work as it returns `AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'xlim'` and just a single sinc function is output

Comment: using `ax.set_xlim(-3,3)` I instead get `NameError: name 'time' is not defined` from `time.sleep(interval)`. Not sure how to fix this @Vaibhav gusain

Comment: try adding `import time` at the start of your program